# Ruby doesn't split `\x1F` instead it returns a triangle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Ruby doesn't split `\x1F` instead it returns a triangle. The value is stored as `["118\u001F119"]` and it should return `["118", "119"]` when trying to access array.

When trying to print `job_template_array[0]`

Output:

```
job_template is 118▼119
```

Expected output:

```
job_template is 118
```

[image]

Comment: Verify that you are using the correct separator and that both, string and separator use the same encoding, e.g. both UTF-8. Other than that, it should work just fine, i.e. `"118\u001F119".split("\x1f")` _does_ return `["118", "119"]` with default UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, your array is something like `job_template_array = ["118\u001F119", "120\u001F121"]`. Of course the first value in the array (`job_template_array[0]`) will then be `"118\u001F119"`. To get an array of `["118", "119"]` you still need to split the string that's returned:

```rb
job_template_array = ["118\u001F119", "120\u001F121"]
first_item = job_template_array[0]
  # "118\u001F119"
split_values = first_item.split("\x1F")
  # ["118", "119"]
puts "job_template is #{split_values[0]}"
  # job_template is 118
```

Comment: Actually array is something like this ` job_template_array = ["118\u001F119\u001F120\u001F121"]`

Comment: Okay, then `job_template_array[0].split("\x1F")` would just return `["118", "119", "120", "121"]`, which you can use in a similar fashion. If the result should be in groups of 2, Rails has a handy helper method for that: [in_groups_of](https://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.0/Array/in_groups_of).